# Consistency Strength of the Failure of Square on Singular Cardinals

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Q1. What is the consistency strength of the failure of square on singular cardinals?

Q2. What are known as partial results in this direction?

Comment: To put emphasis on **everything** defeats the purpose of having that option available. Thus, I removed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One place to start reading is this:

> James Cummings and Sy-David Friedman, "**[$\square$ On the Singular Cardinals](http://www.jstor.org/stable/27590333)**". *The Journal of Symbolic Logic* Vol. **73**, No. 4 (Dec., 2008), pp. 1307-1314.

Comment: Squares, mice, silver machines. What's next, hamsters?

Comment: @Andrej, also Amoeba and other Creatures. But what about sheaves, germs, and so on? And also diamonds, club suites, and other gems.

Comment: Daggers, pistols and hand grenades too!

Comment: You must be kidding about pistols and hand grenades!

Comment: @AndrejBauer I wish. It is unfortunate notation, a bad joke taken too far.

Comment: no hamsters yet, but there are weasels and hybrid mice. Also, I guess the next step now is for someone to come up with $0$-bazooka.

Comment: I expect the idiocy stopped for now, and we will use the more descriptive language of just-sharps, as in $M_n^\sharp$, the sharp for a model with $n$ Woodin cardinals, as opposed to $0^\dagger$, $0$-dagger, which is just the sharp for a model with one measurable cardinal.

Comment: @Andres: But the whole reason I joined to the forces of set theory is that we have unbounded silliness in the naming of objects! (Well, that and it's really interesting and was the only thing that was natural for me in mathematics, but still... silliness is important!) Where else one can write a serious paper titled "Forcing the destruction of large cardinals in the name of choice" without it considered a cardinal sin against mother church? :-) [There is no such paper, but it can be a title of a paper dealing with the collapse of an extendible cardinal under HOD conjecture, or something...]

Comment: Don't forget the paper "A new **construction** of a **non-constructible** $\Delta^1_3$ subset of $\omega$" by Jensen and Johnsbraten.

Comment: @Andrej: If "Turing machine" is alright "Silver machine", named after Jack Silver, should be alright as well.